# is a program with threads in c/c++ supposed to run faster than a serial one?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

I am learning the concept of threads in c/c++. I was trying the examples for
the dot product of two vectors cited in [Pthreads Overview](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Overview).

- [Serial version](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/dotprod_serial.c)
- [Pthreads version](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/dotprod_mutex.c)

I ran both the serial and the thread version of the code and I found that the
serial version was faster than the thread version. I thought it should be the
opposite.

I am running on a single CPU.

Comment: How are you measuring which is faster?  What are the timing results?

Comment: I am measuring the time using "time" command. As @David Alber said the issue is that the program with threads is using vectors four times longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code that link to has a few issues that you need to keep in mind:

1. The serial version is doing an inner product of two length-100 vectors. The parallel version is doing an inner product of two length-400 vectors. You can see that in the array allocation (e.g., `a = (double*) malloc (NUMTHRDS*VECLEN*sizeof(double));` -- `NUMTHRDS` is set to four and `VECLEN` 100 in the code). Therefore, the parallel program is doing four times the amount of work, but with four threads, so the naive assumption is that the serial and parallel programs will have the same run time.
2. The parallel code is demonstrating a mutex for thread synchronization. This may be creating barriers in the code as it runs.
3. The code is using four threads. If your CPU does not have four or more threads, then you cannot expect it to scale.
4. There is an overhead in creating the threads, and with such a small problem it is probably a significant factor.

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is no reason a threaded program should run faster than a serial program, or vice versa.

On a single CPU (or core), you'd have the overhead of switching from one thread to another.

Even on a multiple CPU (core) system, there is the overhead of coordinating threads.

If a problem is [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), it should be relatively easier to solve it faster with multiple threads on multiple cores, but it is still possible to solve it in a way that performs poorly.

With GUI applications, having one thread respond to user actions while another thread carries on computations makes the system more responsive.

See also [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law):

> The speedup of a program using multiple processors in parallel computing is limited by the time needed for the sequential fraction of the program. For example, if a program needs 20 hours using a single processor core, and a particular portion of 1 hour cannot be parallelized, while the remaining promising portion of 19 hours (95%) can be parallelized, then regardless of how many processors we devote to a parallelized execution of this program, the minimum execution time cannot be less than that critical 1 hour. Hence the speedup is limited up to 20×, as the diagram illustrates.

Answer (score 3):

If there's only have a single processor, then it's not much of a surprise.

The threaded code still has to execute the same amount of work as the serial code, and it has the additional burden of context switching to slow it down.

Multi-threaded code will show a speed up if parallelization is possible and there are multiple cores to share the work.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your design. I did not take a look on your code, but parallel programming has its place on accelerating programs.

In some cases, threads are used just to keep the application responsive (it is good). In others, you will use to boost performance, but you need to make parallel processing well planned in a good cpu.

Claudio M. Souza Junior

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of cases where threading doesn't improve performance.

- If your tasks are memory-bound, adding threads usually won't help.  All you'll be doing is increasing contention for bus time and cache slots.  As your threads push each other's data out of the cache, it increases the chances of a cache miss, which will slow things down -- even more so if you have more threads fighting over the bus.
- If it's CPU-bound, the performance gain will be very dependent on how many cores you have.  Once the number of threads exceeds the number of available cores, you won't gain anything.
- If your tasks are working on the same data, you'll need synchronization between them.  That synchronization will mean serializing some sections of code, and if the tasks are too closely related, you end up running one thread at a time anyway.

In each of these cases, you also have to figure in the costs inherent in the use of threads (context switching, extra resources, etc).  If the costs exceed the gains, then you're very likely to actually slow down as a result of threading.